# Escape curly braces in Google Sheets JSDoc customfunction

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc

I'm writing documentation for a function I developed in Google Sheets.  Here's the JSDoc code:

```js
/**
 * Render the results in a string template.
 *
 * @param {"This is {{item1}}."} template
 *        string template for rendering results
 * @customfunction
 */
```

The `{{item1}}` text is causing issues.  When I start typing my function name in Google Sheets, activating autocomplete, I see "Object" listed as the example for my parameter rather than the text with `{{item1}}` included.

I'm trying to figure out how to escape the curly braces so they are rendered in the autocomplete text.  I've tried a number of methods including backslashes in various places and HTML entities, but have not found the needed syntax.